# Вывод данных из двух таблиц в один gridview yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Есть две таблицы без ключей. Для каждой создал модель(Order и Manager). Для Order создал crud gridview и в ее модели прописал следующее

```
public function getManager(){
    return $this->hasMany(Manager::className(), ['order_managerId' => 'manager_id']);
}
```

где `order_managerId` - колонка из таблицы, в которой прописана данная функция, а `manager_id` - колонка из второй таблицы. Хочу вместо id вывести `manager_firstName` из второй таблицы. Вопрос, правильно ли я делаю? Во вью попробовал несколько вариантов,пока выдает ошибку.

UPD. Изменил на

```
public function getManager(){
    return $this->hasOne(Manager::className(), ['manager_id' => 'order_managerId']);
}
```

Все заработало

Answer (score 0):

Да, у вас получается есть relation между моделями, чтобы вывести в gridview  значение из связанной модели просто укажите через точку нужный атрибут, я не тестировал но по логике как-то так, по ссылке посмотрите

```
 'columns' => [
 [
    'attribute' => 'manager',
    'value' => 'manager.manager_firstName'
 ],
 //или так:
 'manager.manager_firstName',
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/653/displaying-sorting-and-filtering-model-relations-on-a-gridview/